# Pipe opencv frames to ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, pipe, mat

I am trying to pipe opencv frames to ffmpeg using rawvideo format, which should accept the input as BGRBGRBGR... encoding the frame before piping is not an option.

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap("cap.avi");

while(1)
{
    cap >> frame;
    if(!frame.data) break;

    // some processing

    cv::Mat array = frame.reshape(0, 1); // to make continuous
    std::string output((char*) array.data, array.total() * array.elemSize());
    std::cout << output;
}
```

with command

```
cap.exe | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 10 -i -
```

gives [this kind of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc48J.jpg) distorted result

I think problem is not related to ffmpeg/ffplay, but something is wrong with my frame to raw conversion

how to convert mat with 3 channels to rawvideo bgr24 format ?

Comment: 3d mat or 3 channel mat?

Comment: does it work if you instead create a 3 channel mat with zero values (black output) or 255 values (white output)?

Comment: @Micka it is 3 channels. interestingly it outputs full blue with 255 * mat::ones

Comment: instead of ::ones can you try Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));?

Comment: OK, white in that case. also tried different colors and get correct color in ffplay end

Comment: if you cv::imshow your video, does it work? is the resolution right?

Comment: You're outputting your data as strings, maybe they're being cut short when they encounter zero bytes in your data?

Comment: Does `std::cout.write((char *)array.data, array.total() * array.elemSize());` work instead of `std::string output((char*) array.data, array.total() * array.elemSize());` and `std::cout << output;`?

Comment: tried that, also tried to stdout uchar element by element and get the same result

Comment: @Micka imshow with waitkey plays it flawlessly

Comment: can you print frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.channels and frame.type before reshape? (without pipe and mat cout)

Comment: reshape doesnt make the Mat continuous. In fact it must be continuous to use reshape. Can you test whether it IS continuous (.isContinuous())?

Comment: If this is on Windows, could it be trying to convert line endings in your output data?

Comment: it is working flawlessly now..